# Laravel get a model collection ordered by a relation column

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to obtain a ranking table based on how much points that has an User.

My User model is (simplified):

```php
namespace Gamify;
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function points()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Gamify\Point');
     }

     public function scopeMember($query)
     {
         return $query->where('role', '=', 'default');
     }
 }
```

And Point model is:

```php
namespace Gamify;
class Point extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'points';

    protected $fillable = array(
        'points',
        'description'
    );

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Gamify\User');
    }
}
```

I'd like to obtain a Collection of users with the sum of its points, ordered by this sum.

Something like this (**this code is only a mockup**):

```php
public static function getRanking($limitTopUsers = 10)
{
    return User::member()->orderBy(sum('points'))->get();
}
```

I've been playing with `User::with()` and scopes and I'm trying not to use `DB::raw()`.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @nextt1's code, this is my final approach:

On User's Model:

```php
public function points()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Gamify\Point')
        ->selectRaw('sum(points) as sum, user_id')
        ->groupBy('user_id');
}

public function getExperiencePoints()
{
    return $this->points()->sum('points');
}
```

And then I've created a function in order to call the ranking:

```php
public static function getRanking($limitTopUsers = 10)
{
    $users = User::Member()->with('points')->get();

    $users = $users->sortByDesc(function ($user) {
        return $user->getExperiencePoints();
    })->take($limitTopUsers);

    return $users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public function points ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Gamify\Point')
            ->selectRaw('sum(points) as sum, user_id')
            ->groupBy('user_id');
    }
```

and use it like

```
        $data = User::with('points')->get();
```

Comment: Hi @nextt1, when I call this code Laravel says "Call to a member function orderBy() on string". Uhm....

Comment: Thanks @nextt1 It's a good starting point, know I'd play in order to get the ranking as I want (order DESC, and columns needed.